# How to disableTheme

Tags: css, xpages

I have an input control with several labels on it, using the extension Library and OneUI the labels a Blank Bold by default. I have a style sheet with this entry in it:

```
.labelGrn10 { font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;color:rgb(95,170, 90);}
```

The labels are all in the same column I have tried just about every combination of disableTheme and applying my style class to these labels one of them is green but I can't for the life of me figure out why they all are not Green as they have the same style applied to them:

```
<xp:td style="width:150px" >
    <xp:label value="Approvers Over Limit :"
    id="approvers_Over_Label1" for="approvers_Over1"
    disableTheme="true" styleClass="labelGrn10">
    </xp:label>
</xp:td>
```

I'm not great on css stuff but this is really a pain in the butt. disableTheme just does not seem to work, or at least the way I think it should.

Comment: Please add some of the rendered HTML output to the question. Also please add more of your code for your labels (to verify that they all have the style class assigned).

Comment: @Per do all the labels on a page need to have the same style applied to them?

Comment: Interesting that if I remove the for="approvers_Over1" from the xp:Label the style sheet .labelGrn10 works. Not sure if there are other implications to this.

Comment: Yes, all labels need the css class assigned. Check output using e.g. Chrome Developer Tools

Answer (score 1):

You could just overwrite the OneUI class with your CSS. A nice documentation of all the classes of OneUI and it's structure is this one: http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the theme but disableTheme is not going to fix it. This is something I dealt a lot and specific to the oneui v2.1 theme. (oneuiv3 has similar problems, different story).

There is a CSS rule in OneUI2.1:

```
.lotusForm td label {
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is more specific than your rule, so it will override yours. You can find these problems just by looking into Firebug.

In case you remove `for` attribute from the label, it will be rendered as span. that's why you don't see the problem in that case.

So the correction you should make would be;

```
.lotusForm td label.labelGrn10 { 
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:10pt; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color:rgb(95,170, 90);
}
```

Since I had this problem once, I have always been defining my style rules specific. If it's going to be a form-table, I have a special class for that. For labels and fields, I'm assigning label and field classes into `td` and my rules are like `table.fieldTable td.label > label` etc.

Comment: that looks great how would one do that if I want it labelGrn10 on one set of labels and labelRed10 on another.

Comment: In the same way. As long as you define the CSS rule in the same level of what theme defines, yours will override.